# Adapt row after smallest image

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap to make a photogrid over photos fetched from the google places api. Now the problem is that the row adapts to the height of the largest image, I want it the otherway around.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-eq-height" ng-repeat="images in main.slicedImages">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" ng-repeat="image in images">
            <div class="hovereffect" ng-click="selected = !selected">
                <img ng-class="{ 'selected_image': selected }" ng-src="{{image.img}}" class="img-responsive stretch_image">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <a class="info" ng-bind="image.name"></a>
                </div>
                <a class="selected_text" ng-show="selected">SELECTED</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how it looks now:
[image]
And I want the rows to adapt to the size of the houses to the right. I dont mind cutting the images that are larger instead of translating them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height and the width of th img setting in css  max-width and max-height equal to 100%

```
my_img_class  {

 max-width: 100%; 
 max-height: 100%;}

}

<img ng-class="{ 'selected_image': selected }" ng-src="{{image.img}}" 
     class="img-responsive stretch_image my_img_class">
```